# how to change the background color of button 1 on click on button 2 and vice versa in flutter

Tags: flutter, button

**Requirement:** I have two buttons, one is time in and other is time out.

Condition for time in enable is

`t2 != ""  || t1 == ""`

and time out enable condition is

`t1 != ""`

time in will be disable when

`t1 != "" && t2==""`

and time out will be disable when

`t1==""`

and when I click on button its text should change to current time.

**Problem:** Everything is working fine at once time, like initially time in button is enable and  timeout button is disable, and when I click on time in button its text and background color changes and time out button gets enable its background color also changes, but when I click on time out button its text changes but time in button is not enable , it is still on disable, I want to make it enable and also its color should change and same for time out button, in short it should perform vice versa.

here is what i have done

```
var timeInText="                 Time in";
  var timeOutText="                 Time out";
  bool timeInBttonPressed=false;
  bool timeOutButtonPressed=false;
  var t1="";
  var t2="";

void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
     _getTime();
}

Widget _timein() {
   //enable
    if(t2 != ""  || t1 == "" ) {
      return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
              text:timeInText,
              bgcolor: timeInBttonPressed ?Colors.blue[200]:Colors.blue[500],
              press: () {
                _getTime();
                setState(() {
                timeInText="                 "+getTime;
                t1=getTime;
                print("t1  "+t1);
                timeInBttonPressed=true;
                });
                
              });
    }
    //disable
      else if(t1 != "" && t2=="") {
      return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
              text:timeInText,
              bgcolor: Colors.blue[200],
              
              );
      } 
    }


     Widget _timeout(){
   //enable
      if(t1 != "") {
        return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
              text:timeOutText,
              bgcolor: timeOutButtonPressed ?Colors.blue[200]:Colors.blue[500],
              press: () {
                _getTime();
                setState(() {
                timeOutText="                 "+getTime;
                //t2=getTime;
                print("t2   "+t2);
                //timeOutButtonPressed=true;      
                timeInBttonPressed=true; 
                                });
                
        });

      }
      //disable
      else if(t1== "") {
        return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
              text:timeOutText,
              bgcolor: Colors.blue[200]);
      }
 }


void _getTime() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('kk:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    setState(() {
      getTime = formattedDateTime;
     print(getTime[0]);
    });
  }
```

**Note:** It is basically an attendance system, in which when user logged in it should do time in first and when time in is done then will able to do time out. and if user wants to time in again then he can and then he must have to do time out to time in again for next day.

Hope all is clear, please help me to fix my problem. Would be very thankful to u.

Comment: So in general if Time In is true its should enable Time out.  So to time in again user must disable timeout ?

Comment: @KrishBhanushali yes, if Time in button pressed is true than it should enable time out. Yes, it should disable timeout